# SQL: Select records from one table if another table with related records has no specific value

Tags: sql

I need to select all records from one table (TOOLBOXES) which don't have related record with a specific field value in another table (TOOLS).

In other words:

1. I have records in TOOLBOXES
2. There are several records of TOOLS related by foreign-key to TOOLBOXES
3. Some TOOLS records has field `kind=HAMMER`.

The question:

How can I select all TOOLBOXES which does NOT have TOOL(kind=HAMMER)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM TOOLBOXES tb 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TOOLS t WHERE tb.col_name_fk = t.col_id AND t.kind = 'Hammer')
```

Alternatively using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT tb.*
FROM TOOLBOXES tb
LEFT JOIN TOOLS t
  ON t.kind = 'Hammer'
 AND tb.col_name_fk = t.col_id
WHERE t.col_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Isn't that an expensive query? I mean there is for every record in TOOLBOXES select from TOOLS will be called.

Comment: @Symon You could compare it with LEFT JOIN approach.

Comment: Whether it is expensive is irrelevant. It is **correct**. *both* are correct.  They are also equivalent  (and could yield the same query plan)

Comment: @wildplasser performance is crucial. look at Sıddık Açıl benchmark

Comment: @Symon . . . Not at all.  With the proper indexes, it will be the fastest solution in many databases and quite competitive in others.

Comment: @wildplasser it's you who talks about sacrifice. Nobody else.

Comment: You saved me! Thanks

Comment: @Hancs Glad to hear you found my answer helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I was going for Lukasz Szozda's Left Join approach as an answer. But, I wanted to run some tests on our very own development database(from my home network so the results are mega-slower than usual) for the above case: two tables and two queries- one with subquery and other with a left join.

Table sizes are respectively:

320131 records
and
1736409 records

Join Query: 5mins 59secs

Subquery with Not Exists: 25mins 46secs

Comment: For the record, this was executed on MSSQL '14. `tb.col_name_fk` and `t.kind` have indices on them. I will provide the execution plans generated as soon as I have access to internal network.